# C# What could be used to remove rows from CSV file without MS Office installed?

Tags: c#, csv

What could be used to remove rows from CSV file without MS Office installed?
Tried EPPlus but it doesn't load CSV file, it only saves as CSV file.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us your attempts? Which specific issues are you experiencing? How about a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Why not a try with `File.ReadAllLines()` followed by a `where()`

Comment: CSV has nothing to do with Office, I'm not sure why you think Office is relevant here. CSV is just a plain text file. You can open it in Notepad if you want, or lots of other programs which are nothing to do with Office. You can also use code to read it quite easily. Even without using a specific CSV-parsing library (although using one might save you some time), you could just read the rows from the text file into an array, go through the array and remove what you don't want, and then overwrite the text file with the altered content of the array

Comment: CSV is a *text* file. It doesn't require Excel. Just write the contents, eg with `File.WriteAllText`. You can't remove lines either. When Excel saves a CSV it overwrites the entire file, it doesn't modify individual lines or cells

Comment: As for EPPlus, its job is to read and write *Excel* files, not CSVs.

Comment: As a CSV is simply a text file with delimiters, there is no reason you can't use the System libraries included with C# to read the file and make any changes that you need to make and save the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could read the file and then delete the row(s) and save it again as file.

```
List<string> rows = File.ReadAllLines("info.csv").ToList();
rows.Remove(rows.Last());
File.WriteAllLines("info.csv", rows);
```